# Is my R Regular Expression matching correctly?

Tags: r, regex, expression

I've struggled with regular expressions in general and recently wrote one that I think is working correctly, but I'm not sure. My question to anyone who takes the time to review my code below - is it theoretically doing what I want it to do?

Purpose: I'm looking through every column in my data set to identify rows that include strings that begin with 'pharmacy - ' followed by any one of 13 drug types and ends with parentheses with a number inside. Here are some examples:

```
pharmacy - oxycodone/acetaminophen (3)

pharmacy - fentanyl (2.83)

pharmacy - hydromorphone (6.8)
```

The code I wrote is below. I believe it is working but would appreciate if any regex experts out there could take a look and confirm that it is doing what I think it's supposed to be doing:

```
viz$med_2 <- apply(viz, 1, function(x)as.integer(any(grep("^pharmacy+[ -]+(codeine|oxycodone|fentanyl|hydrocodone|hydromophone|mathadone|morphine sulfate|oxycodone|oxycontin|roxicodone|tramadol|hydrocodone/acetaminophen|oxycodone/acetaminophen)+[ -]+[(]+[0-9]+", x))))
```

Answer (score 0):

No expert, but your expression looks great, I would maybe just slightly modify that to:

```
^pharmacy\s*-\s*(codeine|oxycodone|fentanyl|hydrocodone|hydromophone|mathadone|morphine sulfate|oxycodone|oxycontin|roxicodone|tramadol|hydrocodone\/acetaminophen|oxycodone\/acetaminophen)\s*\(\s*[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\s*\)$
```

In this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/LvE34y/1/), the expression is explained, if you might be interested.

> Make sure about required escaping for R.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape special characters (with a double backslash `\\` in R) or the regex will throw an error.

In regex, `+` means match a character one or more times. So `pharmacy+` matches `pharmac` followed by one or an infinite number of `y`, which is probably unnecessary.

I'd recommend using `\\s` instead of a simple whitespace. `\\s` matches any whitespace character `[ \t\r\n\f]` and is therefore more versatile.

Here's how I would do it.

```r
viz <- data.frame(
  med_2 = c(
    "pharmacy - oxycodone/acetaminophen (3)",
    "pharmacy - fentanyl (2.83)",
    "pharmacy - hydromorphone (6.8)"
  )
)

# list of the different drug names
drugs_ls <- c(
  "codeine",
  "oxycodone",
  "fentanyl",
  "hydrocodone",
  "hydromophone",
  "mathadone",
  "morphine sulfate",
  "oxycontin",
  "roxicodone",
  "tramadol",
  "acetaminophen"
)

# concatenate and separate drug names with a pipe
drugs_re <- paste0(drugs_ls, collapse = "|")

# generate the regex
med_re <- paste0("^(?i)pharmacy[\\s-]+(?:", drugs_re, ")(?:\\/acetaminophen)?[\\s-]+\\(\\d")

viz$med_2 <- apply(viz, 1, function(x)as.integer(any(grep(med_re, x, perl = TRUE))))

viz
#  med_2
#1     1
#2     1
#3     0
```

The whole regex looks like this:

```
^(?i)pharmacy[\\s-]+(?:codeine|oxycodone|fentanyl|hydrocodone|hydromophone|mathadone|morphine sulfate|oxycontin|roxicodone|tramadol|acetaminophen)(?:\\/acetaminophen)?[\\s-]+\\(\\d
```

- `(?i)` makes the regex case insensitive.
- `(?:)` creates a non-capturing group.
- `?` matches a character / group or nothing.
- `\\d` is a shorthand for `[0-9]`.